# pointers on pointers - reason for performance penalty

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization, clang, inline

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322423/performance-of-operator-overloading-vs-function-call/37322774#37322774), and noticed what I consider as a strange behavior of the compiler.

I first wrote this program (as part of my answer there):

```
class Vector {
private:
  double** ptr;


public:

  Vector(double** _ptr): ptr(_ptr) {}

  inline double& operator[](const int iIndex) const {
    return *ptr[iIndex];
  }
};

extern "C" int test(const double a);

int main() {
    double a[2] = { 1.0, 2.0 };
    Vector va((double**) &a);

    double a1 = va[0];
    test(a1);

    double a2 = va[0];
    test(a2);
}
```

which generates two load instructions when compiled with :

```
clang -O3 -S -emit-llvm main.cpp -o main.ll
```

This can be seen in the llvm-IR (and could be seen in the assembly):

```
    define i32 @main() #0 {
    entry:
      %a.sroa.0.0.copyload = load double*, double** bitcast ([2 x double]* @_ZZ4mainE1a to double**), align 16
      %0 = load double, double* %a.sroa.0.0.copyload, align 8, !tbaa !2
      %call1 = tail call i32 @test(double %0)
      %1 = load double, double* %a.sroa.0.0.copyload, align 8, !tbaa !2
      %call3 = tail call i32 @test(double %1)
      ret i32 0
    }
```

I would expect only one load instruction, since no function with side effect on memory has been called, and I didn't link this object to something with side effects. In fact, when reading the program, I just expect two calls to

```
test(1.0);
```

since my array is constant in memory and everything can be inlined properly.

Just to be sure, I replaced the double pointer by a simple pointer:

```
class Vector {
private:
  double* ptr;

public:
  Vector(double* _ptr): ptr(_ptr) {}

  inline double& operator[](const int iIndex) const {
    return ptr[iIndex];
  }
};

extern "C" int test(const double a);

int main() {
    double a[2] = { 1.0, 2.0 };
    Vector va(a);

    double a1 = va[0];
    test(a1);

    double a2 = va[0];
    test(a2);
}
```

Compiled with the same line , I get the expected result:

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %call1 = tail call i32 @test(double 1.000000e+00)
  %call3 = tail call i32 @test(double 1.000000e+00)
  ret i32 0
}
```

Which looks like way better optimized :)

My question is therefore:

**What reason prevents the compiler to perform the same inlining on the first code sample? Is that double pointers?**

Comment: A pointer to an array of `double` is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer to a double. When you do `&a` you get something of the type `double (*)[2]`. If you need to do C-style casting in C++, then that's a sign of something not being quite right.

Comment: Thanks for the important point raised. Does that explain anything on the rest of the program?

Comment: In your first code, you are trying to access memory outside of what the compiler can see, so there is no reason the compiler would assume that `test` do not modify these memory location.

Comment: and why not in the second case?

Comment: @RegisPortalez In the second case, you access value which are probably on the stack of `main`, so the compiler knows **who** can modify these (since these are not `volatile`). In the first case, you are trying to access value somewhere else, so the compiler cannot assume these value are not modified (by `test` or by some external sources).

Comment: The first code is simply _wrong_. You shouldn't care what object code it produces; technically the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in these lines:

```
double a[2] = { 1.0, 2.0 };
Vector<double> va((double**) &a);
```

`a` is an array of two doubles. It *decays* to a `double *`, but `&a` is **not** a `double **`. *Arrays and pointers are not same animal*.

In fact you have the following: `(void *) a == (void *) &a` because the address of an array is the address of its first element.

If you want to build a pointer to pointer you must create explicitely a true pointer:

```
double a[2] = { 1.0, 2.0 };
double *pt = a; // or &(a[0]) ...
Vector<double> va((double**) &pt);
```

Comment: That is right, compiling with gcc the example of Regis, we get `movabsq <1.0d>, %rbx ; movsd (%rbx), %xmm0`, which indeed means, dereference the pointer of address `0x3FF0000000000000 = 1.0d` .

Comment: With your modification, I get twice the same assembly. (call test(1.0)). 
Damn...

Answer (score 2):

In your second code, the compiler tries to access:

```
va.ptr[0]
```

The compiler can deduce that `va.ptr` is the same as `&a[0]`, and since `a` is a non-volatile local variable of `main`, it also knows that you do not modify `a[0]` (`test` does not have "access" to  `a`), so it can reduce your code to a simple call to `test` with constant value.

In your first code however, the compiler knows that it is trying to access:

```
*(((double**)&a)[index])
```

While `((double**)&a)[index]` maybe deduce by the compiler (this is a compiler-dependent value), you will get a pointer to an address such as `0x3ff0000000000000` (on my computer). What the above expression then tries to do is access the value stored at this address, but this value may be modified by `test`, or even by something else - There is no reason the compiler could assume the value at this address does not change between the first access and the second one.

Note that if instead of using `double**`, you had used `double (*)[2]`, you would have gotten the same output as with the second code and your code would have been well-formed.

---

Your first code is basically equivalent to:

```
extern "C" int test(const double a);

int main() {
    double a[2] = { 1.0, 2.0 };
    double **pp = (double**)&a;
    double *p = pp[0];

    double a1 = *p;
    test(a1);

    double a2 = *p;
    test(a2);
}
```

You will get the same disassembly using your command line.

Assuming an architecture with 4 bytes `double` and pointers, you get something like this at execution:

```
0x7fff4f40 0x3f800000 # 1.0
0x7fff4f44 0x40000000 # 2.0
```

Since `a` is an array of `double`, `&a` may decay to a `double (*)[2]` "with a value of" `0x7fff4f40`.

Now, you are converting `&a` to a `double**`, so you will have a `double **pp` with a value of `0x7fff4f40`. From here, you retrieve a `double *p` using `pp[0]`, since a pointer is also 4 bytes on my hypothetical architectures, you will get `0x3f800000`.

Great, so the compiler may be able to optimize up to this, basically it could create something like this:

```
double *p = (double*) 0x3f800000;

double a1 = *p;
test(a1);

double a2 = *p;
test(a2);
```

Know the one-million dollars question is: What is at the address `0x3f80000`? Well, no ones know, even the compiler. The value at this address might be modified at any time, by a call to `test()` or even by an external source.

I am not an expert about the size constraints on `double` and pointer types, but let's assume an hypothetical architecture where `sizeof(double*) > 2 * sizeof(double)`, the compiler would not even be able to deduce `p` because you would be trying to access values outside `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, in the first case, compiler should know that a has been allocated on the stack of main. Therefore, the address of a in the address of some local stack variable. How the content of this address can be modified by someone else? If test corrupts the caller stack?

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I'll wait for any other answer before accepting it.